# distance from me and markers in array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, distance, google-street-view

I'm trying to show in street view only marker that are distant to me (not mobile and not geocoding, only poistion in map) less then 50 meters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry">   </script>
        <script>
            var markers = [
                ['chelini1', 43.84275, 10.5040667],
                ['chelini2', 43.8428333, 10.5040833],
                ['chelini3', 43.8429333, 10.5040833]
            ];

            var inizio = new google.maps.LatLng(43.8427752, 10.504052);

            function initialize() {
                var panoramaOptions = {
                    position: inizio,
                    pov: {
                      heading: 165,
                      pitch: 0
                    },
                    zoom: 1
                };

                var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('map-      canvas'),panoramaOptions);
                myPano.setVisible(true);

                google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, 'position_changed', function() {
                    var miaposizione = myPano.getPosition();  
                    alert(miaposizione);
                });

                var metri = 50;

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var myMarker = markers[i];
                    coords2 = new google.maps.LatLng(myMarker[1], myMarker[2]);
                    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(miaposizione,coords2);

                    if(distance <= metri) {
                        alert(distance);
                        posizione = new google.maps.LatLng(myMarker[1], myMarker[2])

                        var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: posizione,
                            map: myPano ,
                            icon: 'Azure.png',
                            title: myMarker[0]
                        });

                        //alert(posizione)
                    }else{
                        alert("lontano");
                    }
                }
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="panel"></div>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know that the problem is in distance formula but i can't understand why, for example if i try to put in that formula another point like this (var inizio) it works, but i really need to test the distance between me and every markers...

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable declaration for miaposizione outside of the listener function and then assign to it within. I'm guessing it's undefined when you pass it into conputeDistanceBetween.

```
var miaposizione;

google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, 'position_changed', function() {
                    miaposizione = myPano.getPosition();  
                    alert(miaposizione);
                });
```

*Edit* Am I correct in saying that the distance calculation is being performed on initialize? The variable miaposizione will only be set when the pano position changes which will be after the distances are calculated.

You would need to move the distance calculation into a function outside of initialize and then pass in the new position, e.g:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, 'position_changed', function() {
                var miaposizione = myPano.getPosition();  
                calculateMarkers(miaposizione);
                alert(miaposizione);
            });
```

and then outside init:

```
function calculateMarkers(miasposizione)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var myMarker = markers[i];
                coords2 = new google.maps.LatLng(myMarker[1], myMarker[2]);
                var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(miaposizione,coords2);

                if(distance <= metri) {
                    alert(distance);
                    posizione = new google.maps.LatLng(myMarker[1], myMarker[2])

                    var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: posizione,
                        map: myPano ,
                        icon: 'Azure.png',
                        title: myMarker[0]
                    });

                    //alert(posizione)
                }else{
                    alert("lontano");
                }
            }
 }
```

You would also need to clear the markers each time you run the function (or you'll end up with duplicates).

Comment: Edited answer, hope this is more useful.

Comment: Thnx now i understand about the loop for that must be outside main scope